# NHibernate CreateSQLQuery Transaction Issue

Tags: nhibernate

I have a simple method that does...

```
Session.CreateSQLQuery(syntax).List<T>();
```

The issue is that when I execute this against a stored procedure that enlists a linked server connection I get the following error...

**The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyLinkedServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.**

My question is; how can I tell NHibernate I do not want to use a transaction..?

Thanks..!

Comment: this is not about nhibernate, and any/all queries are run in a transaction either you explicitly declare it or the provider creates it implicitly

Answer (score 2):

I usually do like this:

```
session = PersistenceManager.GetCurrentSession();                
IList<T> lst;
using ( var trans = session.BeginTransaction() )
{
    IQuery sql = session.CreateSQLQuery(syntax);
    lst = slq.List<T>();
    trans.Commit();
}
```